# Open specified URL in the Webview (iOS push)

Tags: ios, user-interface, webview, push

in my iOS App i have an `UIWebView` so how i can open a specified `URL` in the `UIWebView`, with a `push notification`?

If somebody open the App with the `notification`, i want to show a specified Website in 
the `UIWebView`.

Can I bind the `URL` (in background) with the `push notification`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Apple...

> If the app is running and receives a remote notification, the app
>   calls this method to process the notification. Your implementation of
>   this method should use the notification to take an appropriate course
>   of action. ... If the app is not running when a push notification
>   arrives, the method launches the app and provides the appropriate
>   information in the launch options dictionary. The app does not call
>   this method to handle that push notification. Instead, your
>   implementation of the **`application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`** or
>   **`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`** method needs to get the
>   push notification payload data and respond appropriately.

So, there are three possible scenarios:

**1) App is in foreground:** you will have full control, just implement `didReceiveNotification` and do whatever you want.

**2) App is running, but in background:** the action won't be triggered until the user actually open your app using the received notification.

**3) The app is not running:** in this case you should implement `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in order to get the additional info and perform the task.

So the code should look like this for `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if(apsInfo) {
        // Get the URL or any other data
    }
}
```

And this is an approximation for `didReceiveNotification`

```
/**
 * Remote Notification Received while application was open.
 */
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSString *message = nil;
        id aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
        if ([aps isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            message = [aps objectForKey:@"alert"];
        }

        if (message) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notificación"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Aceptar"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
    }

    // Aditional data
    NSString *url = [userInfo objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push URL: %@", url);

    if(url!=nil)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }

    NSLog(@"remote notification: %@",[userInfo description]);
    NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    NSString *alert = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Alert: %@", alert);

    NSString *sound = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"sound"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Sound: %@", sound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

    NSString *badge = [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"];
    NSLog(@"Received Push Badge: %@", badge);
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];

    #endif
}
```